# Cocoapod out of date error on building flutter project

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I updated my flutter to the most recent version in order to use the webview plugin for flutter.

Unfortunately, my cocoa pod is protesting now. On starting the build process, I get the following output:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing
    Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    Finding Podfile changes
      A firebase_auth
      A firebase_core
      R path_provider_linux
      R path_provider_macos
      R shared_preferences_macos
      R shared_preferences_web
      R url_launcher_linux
      R url_launcher_macos
      R url_launcher_web
      - Flutter
      - admob_flutter
      - device_info
      - package_info
      - path_provider
      - shared_preferences
      - sqflite
      - uni_links
      - url_launcher
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `admob_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/admob_flutter/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `device_info` from `.symlinks/plugins/device_info/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `package_info` from `.symlinks/plugins/package_info/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `uni_links` from `.symlinks/plugins/uni_links/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.33.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.14.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_e_2_1.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/e/2/1/FirebaseAnalytics/6.8.3/FirebaseAnalytics.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.14.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_5_9_a.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/5/9/a/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/7.66.0/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_f_4_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/4/e/FMDB/2.7.5/FMDB.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.26.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.14.0)
      In Podfile:
        firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 0.18.0-1, which depends on
          Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 6.26.0)
    You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
     * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/CoreOnly` inside your development pod `firebase_auth`.
       You should run `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` to apply changes you've made.
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1065:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1063:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Things I tried:
Removing the old podfile with `rm ios\Podfile` and relaunching the project.
I have no sudo rights on the apple machine so I cannot do a complete reinstall of cocoapods unfortunately.
Any idea on how I can solve this?

Comment: Have you tried running 'pod repo update' as the message suggests?

Comment: I have, without success sadly. If I try that, I need to execute something with sudo permissions

Answer (score 0):

If `pod repo update` doesn't work, you can try to regenerate the Podfile again. To do this, delete Podfile.lock on `/ios`. Then run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` to fetch the dependencies and generate the Podfile for the iOS build.